# How to get Write-Host to output $true

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script which uses `write-host` to output another powershell script. How can I write out a boolean parameter with the value $true (or $false) **including** the dollar sign:

```
param
(
    [switch] $myParam = $true
)

Write-Host My Param is $myParam
```

I need this to output exactly

```
My Param is $True
```

But it outputs

```
My Param is True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape a $ with a `:

```
Write-Host My Param is `$$myParam
```

Answer (score 3):

This would achieve what I think you want:

```
Write-Host My Param is `$$myParam
```